# How to get salesforce Activity id

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have a salesforce query that extracting users time report

```
SELECT ID,Logged_Date__c ,CreatedBy.Email, CreatedBy.id, CreatedBy.Name, Time_Spent_Hours__c, Activity__c, CaseId__r.CaseNumber, CaseId__r.Account.id, CaseId__r.Account.Name , Utilized__c
FROM Time_and_Placement_Tracking__c
```

The Activity__c returns with the activity text.

I was trying to use Activity__c.Id, Activity__r etc. but all returns with error.

Is there a way to get the Activity id?

Comment: Activity__c should return the Id if your field is a relationship. If you need to pull in information from that object you need to use __r since you are referring to a relationship. So you should be using Activity__r.Id and Activity__c.

Comment: Thank you for your comment

Unfortunately, using Activity__r.Id returns INVALID_FIELD error
and using Activity__c return a string with the activity description

Comment: It seems that Activity__c is a custom text field and not a relationship field. Can you please confirm?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the field definitions.
Assuming you are right and the filed is a custom text field shouldn’t the filed definition has an id?
do I have any way to full it?

Answer (score 0):

**Verify these**

You need to get to the object definition and see the field info. You can use workbench or any other API tool if you are familiar with and get the object and field def's.

1. Check the data type for Activity__c field. It should be a lookup/master relation. If it is not, find the field which ties to Activity object.
2. Open the field to get the API name and use that in the query with a '__r' extension.